# Количество повторений за определенный период

Tags: c#, sql

Имеется таблица
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Хочу вывести причину смерти у которой число повторений больше чем у других причин.

Но за определенный период выбранный в DatePicker .Вывести хочу именно само название причины.

Например за пол года умерло от диабета 6 и 3 от дтп. Вывести что смертность больше от диабета.

Мои попытки

```
 string my_querry6 = "SELECT [Причина смерти], count(*) FROM [Умершие] group by [Причина смерти] where[Дата смерти] between #" + start3.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy") + "# And #" + end3.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy") + "#"; 
            OleDbCommand cmd6 = new OleDbCommand(my_querry6, conn);



            OleDbDataReader dr2 = cmd6.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr2.Read())
            {
                maxsmert.Text = dr2.GetValue(9).ToString() ;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте Вашу строку запроса формировать в виде:

```
//Выводим первую и единственную строку (top 1) сформированную из таблицы [Умершие] с полем [Причина смерти] и агрегатным полем количество, как поле num. 
string my_querry6 = "SELECT top 1 [Причина смерти], count(*) as num FROM [Умершие] ";

//Далее по правилам SQL должна быть клауза where, которая задает условие выбора. Ваш вариант я закоментировал - есть большие сомнения, что оно будет работать
// my_querry6 +=" where[Дата смерти] between #" + start3.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy") + "# And #" + end3.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy") + "#";

//Правильно нужно так через параметры. В OleDb они позиционные и обозначаются символом '?'
my_querry6 += " where[Дата смерти] between ? And ? ";

//Далее условие группировки для вычисления агрегатной функции
my_querry6 +=" group by [Причина смерти] ";

//Условие определяющее порядок следования записей в выходной выборке. Мы просим, чтобы записи выводились в порядке убывания поля num. То есть первой записью будет запись с максимальным значением num.
my_querry6 +=" order by num desc";
```

Блок формирования позиционных параметров Вашего запроса следует поместить сразу после Вашей строки создания команды:

```
        //Ваш код, где Вы создаете комманду
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand cmd6 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(my_querry6, conn);

        //Новый код, где Вы добавляете в команду позиционные параметры 
        cmd6.Parameters.AddWithValue("p1", start3.SelectedDate.Value);
        cmd6.Parameters.AddWithValue("p2", end3.SelectedDate.Value);
```

Полезная ссылка, если Вам недостаточно моих объяснений про параметры https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621695/c-sharp-oledbparameter-with-access-datetime-query

Так как Вы получаете единственную запись, то Вам не нужен цикл `while(...)`. Читать результат можно так:

```
OleDbDataReader dr2 = cmd6.ExecuteReader();
if(dr2.Read())
{
    maxsmert.Text = dr2.GetValue(0).ToString() ;
}
```

В таком виде у Вас все будет работать.

Comment: @Frallen у Вас все заработало?