# c# ms access получить самую частую запись

Tags: c#, ms-access

в столбце есть повторяющиеся записи. нужно найти запись даты(string) с наибольшим количеством

```
cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT max(cnt) AS cnt2 FROM(SELECT date_out, count(date_out) AS cnt FROM people WHERE date_out LIKE '*.01.2019' GROUP BY date_out)", oleConnection);
dreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
int maxCnt = Convert.ToInt32(dreader["cnt2"].ToString()); //ошибка
```

получаю  "Отсутствуют данные для строки или столбца."

Comment: Потому, что Вы не выполнили dreader.read() Гляньте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/971992/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%B4/972249#972249

Comment: `max()` возращает одно значение, поэтому вместо `ExecureReader()` следует использовать метод `ExecuteScalar()`.